# Using PHP/Python to verify ECDSA signature

Tags: php, android, python, php-openssl, boringssl

I write the code to generate ECDSA signature on Android using spongycastle lib. Then I send the sign string and public-key to server (Ubuntu 16.04) and try to use php and python to verify this sign.

I test verify on my android app. It worked well.

I use php-openssl extension and with Python I use ecdsa 0.13. But, both of this failed. I try again, using openssl command and it can't verify too.

I don't know, where I am wrong.

Why is the ECDSA verification failing?

---

Here is my code:

1. Generate signature (android):

   ```
   ECNamedCurveParameterSpec spec = ECNamedCurveTable.getParameterSpec("prime256v1");
   try {
       KeyPairGenerator g = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("ECDSA","SC");
       g.initialize(spec, new SecureRandom());
       KeyPair keyPair = g.generateKeyPair();
       privateKey = keyPair.getPrivate();
       publicKey = keyPair.getPublic();
       ///write public key to pem file
       ......
       FileOutputStream fileOutputStream1 = new FileOutputStream(file1);
       StringWriter writer1 = new StringWriter();
       PemWriter pemWriter1 = new PemWriter(writer1);
       pemWriter1.writeObject(new PemObject("PUBLIC KEY",publicKey.getEncoded()));
       pemWriter1.flush();
       pemWriter1.close();
       String publickeyPem = writer1.toString();
       fileOutputStream1.write(publickeyPem.getBytes());
       fileOutputStream1.close();
       } catch (Exception e) {
           e.printStackTrace();}
       ......
       //Sign and veryfied
        String chuoi = txtChuoi.getText().toString();
        byte[] chuoiInput = chuoi.getBytes("UTF-8");
        Signature sig = Signature.getInstance("NONEwithECDSA","SC");
        sig.initSign(privateKey);
        sig.update(chuoiInput);
        ///SIGN
        byte[] signatureBytes = sig.sign()
        txtMaHoa.setText(Base64.encodeToString(signatureBytes,Base64.DEFAULT));
        sig.initVerify(publicKey);
        sig.update(chuoiInput);
        ///VERIFIED
        txtGiaiMa.setText(sig.verify(signatureBytes)+"");
        ///Write string sign in txtMahoa to file
        .......
   ```
2. Output I have Signature and publickey are:

   ```
   (Signature string) MEYCIQC7Hz631IFGsUOogcRLeN99uM9hWgLr+LGzuJvR/6nBrgIhAMXgZcvXyMRCAELXlNNS1a9j iAT1x0q2C5Mdu+2aZKtN
   ```

   (Publickey)

   ```
   -----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
   MFkwEwYHKoZIzj0CAQYIKoZIzj0DAQcDQgAEj07XEM+ulPyrdsfAf9prN2L2dNUd /Yy0rABcFdueAwYUf86f8Cc93Ws6sxzIvf2iKOapFby7EjHewjhLM/z7Qg==
    -----END PUBLIC KEY-----
   ```
3. Verify using PHP:

   ```
   $pubkeyid = openssl_pkey_get_public("/var/www/html/ca.pem");

   $data = "nguyen tran thanh Lam";

    $signature =
     "MEYCIQC7Hz631IFGsUOogcRLeN99uM9hWgLr+LGzuJvR/6nBrgIhAMXgZcvXyMRCAELXlNNS1a9jiAT1x0q2C5Mdu+2aZKtN";
   $ok = openssl_verify($data, $signature, $pubkeyid);
   if ($ok == 1) {
   echo "good";
   } elseif ($ok == 0) {
      echo "bad";
   } else {
   echo "ugly, error checking signature";
   }
   ?>
   ```

Comment: Your Output Signature has a Blank in it _**9j iA**_

Comment: No, it is my typing mistake.

Comment: Possible to get a Link to _"/var/www/html/ca.pem"_, i want to verify with `pyopenssl`?

Comment: ??? It can reach file ca.pem but I have a problem: the String signature generate in Android ---> I encode it to Base64 and send to server. But when I decode it with PHP, it may be not like sign in android. So I can verify this sign on android but use php, it fail. PyOpenSSL?  I have not used, can you guide me. Thanks.

Comment: PyOpenSSL [signing-and-verifying-signatures](https://pyopenssl.org/en/stable/api/crypto.html#signing-and-verifying-signatures)

Comment: I have a question. Example ---- b"sha256"? "b" is a binary (built-in funtion or I must convert string sha256 to binary?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **Comment**: ... but the verify function don't return anything. So I not sure

If `crypto.verify(...` don't throw an Error, this means Verify is OK. See updated Code below.
**Verify with using WRONG Certificat, Signature or Data**.

---

> **Comment**: what do you think about add base64.b64decode. ... because in android code I have this `linetxtMaHoa.setText(Base64.encodeToString(signatureBytes,Ba‌​se64.DEFAULT));`

`PEM` is already `base64`, check if the above `.setText(Base64...` can omitted. For now I have updated the Code below with `base64.b64decode`.

---

> **Question**:  Example ---- b"sha256"? "b" is a binary (built-in funtion or I must convert string sha256 to binary?)

Works for me only as String ([digest-names](https://pyopenssl.org/en/stable/api/crypto.html#digest-names)), for example:

```
import pem, base64
from OpenSSL import crypto

signature  = b"MEYCIQC7Hz631IFGsUOogcRLeN99uM9hWgLr+LGzuJvR/6nBrgIhAMXgZcvXyMRCAELXlNNS1a9jiAT1x0q2C5Mdu+2aZKtN"

# As Creator of the Signatur do additional base64 encoding!
signature = base64.b64decode(signature)

data = "nguyen tran thanh Lam"

certificate = pem.parse_file('Android.pem')[0]
cert = crypto.load_certificate(crypto.FILETYPE_PEM, certificate.as_bytes())

try:
    crypto.verify(cert=cert, signature=signature, data=data, digest='sha256')
except crypto.Error as exp:
    print('crypto.Error:{}'.format(exp.args))

>>>crypto.Error:([('', 'ECDSA_do_verify', 'bad signature')],)
```

> **Note**: Throws `crypto.Error` because not using the `certificate` which created the `signature`.

---

> [OpenSSL.crypto.verify(certificate, signature, data, digest)](https://pyopenssl.org/en/stable/api/crypto.html#signing-and-verifying-signatures)
>
> Verify the signature for a data string.
>       certificate is a X509 instance corresponding to the private key which generated the signature.
>       signature is a str instance giving the signature itself.
>       data is a str instance giving the data to which the signature applies.
>       [digest is a str instance naming the message digest type of the signature, for example b"sha256"](https://pyopenssl.org/en/stable/api/crypto.html#digest-names).
>
> New in version 0.11.

Comment: It has error with me: ( certificate = pem.parse_file('ecc_publickey1.pem')[0]
IndexError: list index out of range)

Comment: If I remove [0] it has error too: (cert = crypto.load_certificate(crypto.FILETYPE_PEM, certificate.as_bytes())
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'as_bytes')

Comment: And, I update the signature and publickey here: (sig=MEUCIEa5FlEm3mBp79ZG5f+rZdZ8o0eDWrAEE+TI8yZ+1501AiEA0dDMvdDuFLkr9HPWE1RgHcxixAE9A11GNnQ/Iuut/Ts=), (origin string=this is origin string) and (public key = -----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MFkwEwYHKoZIzj0CAQYIKoZIzj0DAQcDQgAEDDu15deKy7eyVl9eLFmb/iNik1vq
GyeC5sD9xB8mhVwROUinznICvu76bvCmDuSopp4PMRd3GRBPOLyg1uSrEQ==
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----). I use ECDSA, why you output is RSA?

Comment: Your `PEM` is invalid!  _**IndexError**_ means there is **no** Certificate in the File. Read about [what-is-a-pem-file](https://serverfault.com/questions/9708/what-is-a-pem-file-and-how-does-it-differ-from-other-openssl-generated-key-file)

Comment: ok, let me check again. When I have result I will show you. Thanks for your help :D

Comment: _"why you output is RSA?"_ : You haven't provided a Link to your `PEM`, so didn't have Access to your `PEM`, I used another Certificate to show you how to use `pyopenssl`.

Comment: If I add base64 decode like this (signature  = base64.b64decode("""MEQCICBM16pLFDdunmozzmc9VH20PcA4j+oK/CwbI+xzyGo0AiBr8bVHQ5ebubj/gFaeYeO7ceNdekMNkuCnn6H7rf5xUg=="""))------> it don't have error but don't return any thing. How can I get return? May be this code right?

Comment: what do you think about add base64.b64decode. I think it maybe right because in android code I have this linetxtMaHoa.setText(Base64.encodeToString(signatureBytes,Base64.DEFAULT));-----> but the verify function don't return anything. So I not sure, I do not have much experience with python.

Comment: @nistelrooy: Updated my Answer